# How to align bootstrap div content vertically middle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I have three divs in a row. The first div will receive content dynamically. According to the height of my first div, i need to align the content of second and third div vertically middle. I use bootstrap classes for my div.

I expect output like below. Can somebody help.

[image]

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col-lg-3 child">
    <p>It is a dynamic content</p>
    <p>Sample</p>
    <p>Sample</p>
    <p>Sample</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 child">
    <p>Static content which needs to be aligned vertically middle</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 child">
    <p>Sample</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @HariomSingh : i added my code. Pls check my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used only Boostrap classes - vertically centered with *align-items-center* class and horizontal center with *justify-content-center* class.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>

    </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>It is a dynamic content</p>
        <p>Sample</p>
        <p>Sample</p>
        <p>Sample</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>Static content which needs to be aligned vertically middle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>Sample</p>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use default Bootstrap classes. I changed `.parent` into `.row` and added `.d-flex` and `.align-items-center` to achieve the desired result.

Absolute positioning for the flex items is not necessary and removed.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="col-lg-3 child">
    <p>It is a dynamic content</p>
    <p>Sample</p>
    <p>Sample</p>
    <p>Sample</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 child">
    <p>Static content which needs to be aligned vertically middle</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 child">
    <p>Sample</p>
  </div>
</div>
```